# Android implement infinite scroll using pagination from API

Tags: android, json, laravel-4, pagination, android-volley

I have an API with a pagination scheme, like that:

```
-meta: {
    -pagination: {
        total: 100
        count: 20
        per_page: 20
        current_page: 1
        total_pages: 5
     -links: {
            next: "http://dev.app/api/posts?page=2"         
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to find a way to implement that on my android app using volley and infinite scroll, the app has to read the json pagination from the API and scroll down to 20 items and than autoload to the next page, the problem is that when I get to "page=2" and I hit LoadMore button again it still getting the page 2 and not page 3, I mean, the current page is always 1, I don't know why this is happening, what I tried to do is:

```
  public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    ConnectionDetector cd;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();

    //Progress Dialog
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    //make json parser Object
    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> restaurant_list;

    //Restaurant Json array
    JSONArray restaurants = null;

    JSONObject pagination = null;
    JSONObject link = null;

    private String url_posts = "http://dev.app/api/posts";

    //Flag for current page
    private String nPage;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        //Check for Internet Connection
        if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
            //Internet connection not present
            alert.showAlertDialog(MainActivity.this, "Internet Connection Error", "Please Check Your Internet Connection");
            //stop executing code by return
            return;
        }

        restaurant_list = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        new LoadRestaurants().execute();



        Button btnLoadMore = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        btnLoadMore.setText("Show More");

        getListView().addFooterView(btnLoadMore);

        btnLoadMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                url_posts = nPage;

                new LoadRestaurants().execute();
            }
        });


    }


    class LoadRestaurants extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        //Show Progress Dialog
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading All Restaurants...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg) {
            //building parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();



            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_posts, "GET", params);


            try {
                restaurants = json.getJSONArray("data");

                JSONObject meta = json.getJSONObject("meta");

                pagination = meta.getJSONObject("pagination");

                link = pagination.getJSONObject("links");

                nPage = link.getString("next");

                if (restaurants != null) {
                    //loop through all restaurants
                    for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);

                        //Creating New Hashmap
                        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                        //adding each child node to Hashmap key
                        map.put("id", c.getString("id"));
                        map.put("look1", c.getString("look1"));
                        map.put("look2", c.getString("look2"));
                        map.put("comment", c.getString("comment"));

                        //adding HashList to ArrayList
                        restaurant_list.add(map);
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {

            //dismiss the dialog
            pDialog.dismiss();


            //Updating UI from the Background Thread
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            MainActivity.this, restaurant_list,
                            R.layout.feed_item, new String[]{
                            "id", "look1", "look2", "comment"}, new int[]{
                            R.id.profilePic, R.id.name, R.id.txtUrl});

                    setListAdapter(adapter);

                    ListView lv = getListView();
                    int currentPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                    lv.setSelectionFromTop(currentPosition + 1, 1);



                }
            });


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what problem you are facing from above code?

Comment: @Diva I have to pass the current page to above code statically, I want volley to read the api and automatically knows which is the current page and if it has more data to load, move to the next page link

Comment: ok , you need to listen to scroll and hit the same apis with updated curemt [age number

Comment: yes but where are you are listing to scroll? i could not see that code